# Does L'Hopital's rule imply that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ always?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, fake-proofs, paradoxes

My question is summarised as follows:

> Is $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $$
> always equal to $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $$
> or can we only deduce values of limits using differentiation in the forward direction, ie we can't deduce that the value of $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $ is the same as $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $?

Logically I cannot see why this shouldn't be true (ie I can't see why we can't also integrate the numerator and denominator). HOWEVER, the following result seems to throw some doubt on this:

Consider the identity
$$f(x)^2\frac{d}{dx}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}+g(x)^2\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\equiv0$$
$$\implies\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}\equiv-\frac{f(x)^2}{g(x)^2}$$
On applying L'Hopital's rule we obtain
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}\equiv\lim_{x\to a}-\frac{f(x)^2}{g(x)^2}\implies\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}\equiv\lim_{x\to a}-\frac{f(x)^2}{g(x)^2}$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)^2}{g(x)^2}\equiv\lim_{x\to a}-\frac{f(x)^2}{g(x)^2}$$
which is obviously false.

Any help explaining this apparent proof would be appreciated.

Comment: No. L'Hopital doesn't always apply. Just take $f(x) = 1, g(x) = x$ and take the two ratios as $x \to 1$. They won't agree.

Comment: @0XLR Oh. So when does it apply?

Comment: The answer below lists those requirements. In fact, you will notice that L'Hopital is actually quite a unusual rule that only applies in unusual cases.

Comment: Your questions are always interesting.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I am glad you like them, I really appreciate your comment! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard theorem says that both limits are equal **if**

1. $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on an interval containing $a$, with the possible exception of $a$ itself
2. $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to a} |g(x)| = \infty$
3. $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists.

You can use it to find the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ from the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ or to find the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ from the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$, but you do need to know that the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists.

EDIT: Your "apparent proof" is bogus because it violates assumption (2).

Comment: Ok, so assuming the limit exists then doesn't my question still stand?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent No. If you look at the requirements above, it is not enough for the limits to exist. You also need either $f(x) \to 0, g(x) \to 0$ or $f(x) \to \infty, g(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: You also need the requirement that $g'(x)\neq 0$ near $a$. A famous counterexample is $f(x) = x + \cos x \sin x$ and $g(x)=f(x)e^{\sin x}$. Trivially $f(x)/g(x)$ has no limit as $x\to\infty$, but $f'(x)/g'(x)\to 0$.

Comment: @0XLR So let's say all the conditions are met. Then what's wrong with my proof?

Comment: Professor Robert, I'm not quite clear, sorry; how exactly does my 'proof' violate assumption $2$?

Comment: $|f(x)/g(x)|$ and $|g(x)/f(x)|$ don't both go to $0$ or both go to $\infty$.  If one goes to $0, the other goes to $\infty$ and vice versa.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your first question is No.

Take $$f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac 1x)$$
and
$$g(x)=x$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

But

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
Does not exist.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: In fact the theorem provides only a sufficient and unnecessary condition :-) even if you are remotely a fan of "Juventus" I have voted you ahahah.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am a fan of AS Roma, Lazio, Inter, Fiorentina, .... Italy. ahahah dear Sebastian

Comment: @Sebastiano I undetstood that you are a fan of Torino.

Comment: I am from Inter...you are in error ahahahahah

Comment: @Sebastiano You are a Champion but with Mourinho hahaaha

Comment: @Sebastiano Good night friend {}{}{}{}

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Ahhahha ten years ago :-/ good night.

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, let's let $F(x)=f(x)/g(x)$ and $G(x)=g(x)/f(x)$. The identity you call attention to can be written as

$${F'(x)\over G'(x)}=-{f(x)^2\over g(x)^2}$$

and we also, of course, have

$${f(x)^2\over g(x)^2}={f(x)/g(x)\over g(x)/f(x)}={F(x)\over G(x)}$$

Now **if** L'Hopital's rule applied to the limit for $F/G$, then we would have

$$\lim{f(x)^2\over g(x)^2}=\lim{F(x)\over G(x)}\color{red}{=}\lim{F'(x)\over G'(x)}=-\lim{f(x)^2\over g(x)^2}$$

(where the red equal sign is the L'Hopital step).  But in order to apply L'Hopital to the ratio $F/G$, we must have either $\lim F(x)=\lim G(x)=0$ or $\lim F(x)=\lim G(x)=\pm\infty$, and this cannot happen, since $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are reciprocals (i.e., $G(x)=1/F(x)$). In short, there is no paradox, because L'Hopital does not apply to the ratio $F/G$.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> Is $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $$
> always equal to $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $$

> I can't see why we can't also integrate the numerator and denominator

As other answers have already noted, these limits are not always equal (even when they exist).

Let’s try to find the simplest possible explanation here. We start by noting that differentiation produces only one answer, but integration (in the sense of antidifferentiation) produces infinitely many answers, expressed using a “constant of integration”. Changing this constant does not affect the first limit in the question, but we expect that it does affect the second.

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be functions where $f_2(x) = f_1(x) + c$ for some constant $c \neq 0$. Then, assuming that the relevant limits exist and are finite,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_2(x)}{g(x)} &= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_1(x) + c}{g(x)} \\
&= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} + \lim_{x \to a} \frac{c}{g(x)} \\
&= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} + c \cdot \lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{g(x)} \\
&= \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)} + c \cdot \frac{1}{\lim_{x \to a} g(x)} \\
&\neq \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)}
\end{align*}

So we were right: the second limit changes (in at least some cases). Therefore, the limits are not always equal.